# Is it "Adapted to" or "Adapted for" ? Knowing that its phrasal verb is "adapt to"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

I can not determine whether the right prepositional adj. is:

> "Adapted to" or "Adapted for".

I have confused with these two prepositions but I'm sure that the phrasal verb is always followed by "to", so, what about the adjective ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Adapted to" and "Adapted for" are both valid constructions, but they do not mean the same thing.

"Adapted to" generally means that something has changed to fit its own environment. For example, "People have adapted to the difficult living conditions in the Arctic."

"Adapted for" suggests changes made to something by someone else. For example, "The book was adapted for the stage by Ann Williams." or "The vehicle was adapted for off-road travel by the engineering students at University *X*."

Comment: You solved my problem today! thx